# C++ library to replace the standard cstdio

Tags: c++, file-io, windows-7

I want a feature that when my application crashes, the already written logs are kept in the log file. But using the `fopen()/fwrite()` from `cstdio` library seems not to do this. So when my application crashes, the log file is 0KB. I was wondering if there's any file handling library can do this? E.g. Boost?

Comment: have you tried `flush`? But otherwise this is either a bit broad or "looking for tool, library, etc."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Classic XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The solution is to ensure your log file is flushed, not to switch to some new API in hopes that it solves the problem.

Look up `fflush`; call it when you want to ensure writes are committed to disk.

Answer (score 3):

Calling [`fflush`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fflush) after every line of output should get the contents into the file. It will slow down the output significantly though.

You could also check out the native I/O calls for your OS, but that won't be portable.